# Why doesn't this regex work in bash when it works on regex101?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string stored in a bash variable as follows:

```
$ echo "$str"
Product 1  (1.0.0) | Product 2  (2.0.0) | Product 3  (19.2.1) | Product 4  (12.9.0) | Product 5  (3.2.8) | Product 6 (4.0.2)
```

I require a regex matching to return me the version number of Product 3 "x.x.x" within the parenthesis (i.e. 19.2.1 in this instance)

I have come up with the current regex matching, however the string doesn't seem to match, even though on regex101 the match does return the version number. Could you tell me what I have done wrong and how can I correct this? I'm a newbie in bash scripting

```
$ regex="Product\s+3\s+\(((?:[0-9]+\.?){3})\)"
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" || echo "no match"
no match
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "no match"
no match
$ [[ "$str" =~ "$regex" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" || echo "no match"
no match
$ [[ "$str" =~ "$regex" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "no match"
no match
```

Comment: There are many different regular expression syntaxes supported by different tools.  The syntax supported by Bash is [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).  It does not support `(?:...)`.

Comment: `regex="Product[[:space:]]+3[[:space:]]+\(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2})\)"` should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Nick's comment on my question, solved the problem.

```
$ regex="Product[[:space:]]+3[[:space:]]+\(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2})\)"
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || echo "no match"
19.2.1
```

Thanks to pjh who also provided research material on POSIX ERE